# merging changes beteen two tags onto another branch - CVS

Tags: merge, branch, cvs

I want to merge the changes made to all the files between two tags and merge those changes with another branch in CVS.

I can get the files changed from cvs diff -N -c -r revison_1  -r revision_2 | grep "Index:" > diff.out

but hw to merge the changes made to these files to a different branch.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with cvs `up`. With the working directory in the branch you want the changes to be merged:

`$ cvs up -j revision_1 -j revision_2`